# Apktool doesnt compile properly via command line

Tags: decompiler, apktool

I am able to decompile the file using "advanced apktool" but when i use apktool alone via command line I get this error:

> I: Baksmaling... I: Loading resource table... Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Could not decode arsc file at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:55) at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibResources.java:315) at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.loadMainPkg(AndrolibResources.java:50) at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResTable(AndrolibResources.java:43) at brut.androlib.Androlib.getResTable(Androlib.java:44) at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.getResTable(ApkDecoder.java:148) at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.decode(ApkDecoder.java:98) at brut.apktool.Main.cmdDecode(Main.java:128) at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:65) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Expected: 0x001c0001, got: 0x00000000 at brut.util.ExtDataInput.skipCheckInt(ExtDataInput.java:48) at brut.androlib.res.decoder.StringBlock.read(StringBlock.java:45) at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readPackage(ARSCDecoder.java:97) at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTable(ARSCDecoder.java:82) at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:48) ... 8 more" My apk does have a res folder i can see it using dexindexor app on my phone and it decompiled using other decompilers (that use apktool) its just apktool doesn't decompile it on its own properly.

Its the same when i try a different comnputers. I'm using winxp 32 jre 1.7, win7 64 jre 1.8.

Why is this happenning and how do I fix it?

Comment: It's not clear from your question *how* you run apktool via command line? What is your command?

Comment: Update the apktool , it shud solve the issue

Comment: I run the command "apktool d myapp.apk"    - Is there any other command :-(

Comment: Im using the latest version and i have the same issues.

Comment: Ive been at this for over a week!! What is up with this damn software!  Its working for everyone else so its not a bug   but i tried 7 versions on 4 computers and i get the same stupid error!!

Comment: Have you tried unpacking the apk with a normal zip tool? It might be a malformed zip file.

Comment: The apk is not malformed because advancedapktool decompiles it just fine. It apktool. I get this with every apk i decompile.